# L2TP connection error via Windows 8 client

Tags: windows, l2tp

When I try to connect to an L2TP server via Windows 8 client I receive **error 789:The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the remote...**

But I have no problem while connecting to this very same server from other clients, even other Windows 8 machine.

Any help?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your ISP.

Comment: @Pazis Then, why my phone can connect?